# Can't access variable from within a function's scope

Tags: javascript, django

I have this script to create google maps with markers template inside my Django project:

```
<script>
  function initMap() {

    const shop = {
      lat: 45.0203018,
      lng: -88.318316
    };

    const map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: shop,
    });  
  
    const vehicles = {{ vehicles|safe }};
    for(i = 0; i < vehicles.length; i++){
      const pos = new google.maps.LatLng(vehicles[i]['lat'],vehicles[i]['lon']);
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map,
        label: vehicles[i]['number'],
      }); 
    
      const id = vehicles[i]['truck']     
      marker.addListener("click", () => {
        console.log(id)
        window.location = "{% url 'invent:truck' id %}";
      });  
    };   
  };

  window.initMap = initMap;
</script>
```

But it doesn't see variable `id` inside the `addListener` function. And if I put the variable inside the function it doesn't see the `vehicles` variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `"{% url 'invent:truck' %}" + id`

Comment: @Titus That's not the problem I am trying to solve. I can't access ```id``` at that level at all.

Comment: maybe an IIFE will come to the rescue?

Comment: I don't know `django` but it seems to me that you're trying to access a client side variable (`id`) from the server side which is not possible. This `{% .. %}` looks like a server side template, in that context, `id` doesn't exist.

Comment: put the id inside the event callback :
marker.addListener(....
   const id = ...

Comment: I've just added a ```console.log(id)``` to make it clearer. That ```console.log(id)``` doesn't return anything. It's all client side.

Comment: @Goran.it Then It won't see ```vehicles``` variable.

Comment: Did you try it .. it must see the vehicles variable as its in the same context..

Comment: A warning, `{{ vehicles|safe }}` is not at all safe and can expose you to Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks. Use the [`json_script` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
const id = vehicles[i]['truck']
const url = "{% url 'invent:truck' 1234 %}".replace(/1234/, id.toString());
marker.addListener("click", () => {
  window.location = url
});
```